# VHDL process, nested if statement execution

Tags: vhdl, process

I am relearning VHDL and have a question about the code below. This is from a tutorial I have been following. When a button is pressed, an LED gets turned on after the person releases their finger from the button. I am confused about the order of execution in the process.
Specifically this line:
if i_Switch_1 = '0' and r_Switch_1 = '1' then

I have been reading that inside processes the code is executed sequentially, so I do not understand how this gets executed, since they are assigned to the same value right before.

Thanks

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Clocked_Logic is
    port(
        i_Clk : in std_logic;
        i_Switch_1 : in std_logic;
        o_LED_1 : out std_logic);

end entity Clocked_Logic;

architecture RTL of Clocked_Logic is

signal r_LED_1 : std_logic := '0';
signal r_Switch_1 : std_logic := '0';

begin
    p_Register : process (i_Clk) is
    begin
    if rising_edge(i_Clk) then
        r_Switch_1 <= i_Switch_1;

        if i_Switch_1 = '0' and r_Switch_1 = '1' then
            r_LED_1 <= not r_LED_1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process p_Register;


o_LED_1 <= r_LED_1;

end architecture RTL;
```

Comment: you are dealing with hardware, not software ... there is a delay between input states and output states

Comment: Signal assignment semantics and delta cycles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Comment: The answer to this question is teaching the basics of VHDL and it's a Q&A site, not a step-by-step tutorial or discussion site. I won't write an answer because there's tons on the internet. But... Get yourself away from the trap you've walked into: seeing VHDL as a programming language that executes software instructions. It's a descriptor language for describing the behaviour of digital logic circuits. It behaves very differently. Signals are not program variables, they are scheduled in a simulator and circuitry in a chip. It's for you to teach yourself the basics. Good luck with it, enjoy.

Comment: There is no "execution", as these are hardwares. Btw you can learn C/C++ in 2 months but not HDL languages cz there are more to it. Good luck 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is essentially what the hardware looks like.  The i_ prefix means input or intermediate signal to a register.  What you have is one register for detecting a falling edge on the Switch_1 signal and another register for toggling the LED output whenever a falling edge occurs on the Switch_1 signal.  Note that wrapping the output of a register back to the input through a NOT gate creates a toggle flop.  The toggle flop is enabled (toggles) whenever a falling edge occurs on the Switch_1 signal.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left that out.  @TonyM is correct, the i_CLK signal in the VHDL code should be connected to the CLK inputs of the registers in the drawing.

Comment: Yup all done!  Fixed a copy and paste error with the LED register too.  Thanks @TonyM